# Magento 2.1 Multiple Store Views Errors

Tags: magento-2.1, apache

I have one installation (2.1.4) running www.mysite.com - this site works fine

In admin I have setup a second website www.mysecondsite.com - this site also works fine

I have setup a third website (this one is where I am struggling). There are two store views, one with a code of 'en' and one with a code of 'cy'

I am trying to run each store view with the following urls:

en = http://mythirdsite.com/
cy = http://cy.mythirdsite.com/

However when I go to try each of these urls I get the following errors:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity.
#0 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/Website.php(46): Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->get('en')
#1 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(136): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Website->getAllowedStoreIds('en')
#2 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(122): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->readStoresData()
#3 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(85): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData()
#4 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(154): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()
#5 /home/public_html/mysite.com/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)
#6 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(29): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL)
#7 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL)
#8 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL)
#9 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php(793): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/base...', 'store')
#10 /home/public_html/mysite.com/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/Store/Interceptor.php(232): Magento\Store\Model\Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#11 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php(597): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->isCurrentlySecure()
#12 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Store\Model\Store->getBaseUrl('link', NULL)
#13 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->___callParent('getBaseUrl', Array)
#14 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Store\\M...', 'getBaseUrl', Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), Array, 'urlSignature')
#15 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Url/Plugin/Signature.php(64): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('link', NULL)
#16 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Theme\Model\Url\Plugin\Signature->aroundGetBaseUrl(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#17 /home/public_html/mysite.com/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/Store/Interceptor.php(143): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getBaseUrl', Array, Array)
#18 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php(1293): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->getBaseUrl()
#19 /home/public_html/mysite.com/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/Store/Interceptor.php(648): Magento\Store\Model\Store->getStorePath()
#20 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreCookieManager.php(70): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->getStorePath()
#21 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php(70): Magento\Store\Model\StoreCookieManager->deleteStoreCookie(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor))
#22 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(52): Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#24 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#27 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/public_html/mysite.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#30 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#32 /home/public_html/mysite.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)
#33 /home/public_html/mysite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 /home/public_html/mysite.com/theschoolprintshop.co.uk/index.php(43): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
```

I can see it is not finding the store view code 'en', yet it does exist.

In my root installation folder I have sub folders for each site, each with their own index.php and .htaccess files

If I change the code in both the index.php and .htaccess files to use the third website store code instead of the store view code, the site works fine. However I need to use the store views for obvious reasons.

Please can anyone tell me what to check

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer to my question as I re-read my own question :) and realised where I went wrong. So for my own records and anybody else, in the index.php for my store view I had the following...

```
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'en';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
```

To look at a store view it must be this instead...

```
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'en';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
```